# Show that $\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n}\leq ({\frac{2^n-2}{n-1}})^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

If $n$ is a positive integer, show that

> $\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n}\leq ({\frac{2^n-2}{n-1}})^{n-1}$

This is how I tried to solve it:
the given inequality is equivalent to

$\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n-1}\leq ({\frac{2^n-2}{n-1}})^{n-1}$

$\iff \sqrt[n-1] {\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n-1}}\leq \frac{2^n-2}{n-1}$

Now, we know that

$\sqrt[n-1] {\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n-1}} \leq \frac{\binom{n}{1}+...+\binom{n}{n-1}}{n-1}$

Hence, we are left with proving $\binom{n}{1}+...+\binom{n}{n-1} \leq 2^n-2$

or, $\binom{n}{0}+...+\binom{n}{n} \leq 2^n$

Can we prove the last inequality? Am I on the right track? Thanks for help.

Comment: I haven't followed your reasoning, but $\binom{n}{0}+...+\binom{n}{n}= (1+1)^n = 2^n$.

Comment: You used AM-GM inequality in the wrong way. It should be $\sqrt[n-1] {\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n-1}} \leq \frac{\binom{n}{1}+...+\binom{n}{n-1}}{n-1}$.

Comment: Attempt a proof by induction.

Comment: @ LeGrandDODOM Thanks for your help with the first comment. I've correctly edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @LeGrandDODOM from [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) that $\sqrt[n-1] {\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n-1}} \leq \frac{\binom{n}{1}+...+\binom{n}{n-1}}{n-1}$.

However, note that $\binom{n}{1}+...+\binom{n}{n-1}=2^n-2$ which follows from the binomial theorem.

$\sqrt[n-1] {\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n-1}} \leq \frac{2^n-2}{n-1}$.

This gives us that ${\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n-1}} \leq (\frac{2^n-2}{n-1})^{n-1}$.

From here, $\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{1}...\binom{n}{n}\leq ({\frac{2^n-2}{n-1}})^{n-1}$.

Thus, you appear to mistaken.

Comment: Is the question wrong?

Comment: @tatan Yes, it appears so.

Comment: @tatan For example, take $n=4$.

Comment: @ MXYMXY It appears that I made a really huge mistake by replacing all the $\leq$ with $\geq$. Thanks for pointing out.